# TestFX doesn't work when testing setOnKeyPressed on a Pane

Tags: javafx, testfx

I have a problem while testing a JavaFX application with TestFx.
I put a sample, using just a VBox instead of a BorderPane that i use in real application. I just fill the pane with a canvas, to not have it empty, but with or without nothing changes.

```
public class MainPanelTest extends ApplicationTest {

    Pane toTest;
    boolean pressed = false;

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) {
        toTest= new VBox(new Canvas(800,800));
        toTest.setOnKeyPressed(e -> {
                     System.out.println("Pressed");
                     pressed = true;
        });
        stage.setScene(new Scene(toTest));
        stage.show();
        stage.toFront();
    }

    @Test
    public void test_keyPressed_D() {
        clickOn(toTest);
        press(KeyCode.D);
        WaitForAsyncUtils.waitForFxEvents();
        assertTrue(pressed);
    }
}
```

If instead of a Pane, I use a TextField for instance, all is working:

```
public class MainPanelTest extends ApplicationTest {

    TextField toTest;
    boolean pressed = false;

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) {
        toTest= new TextField();
        toTest.setOnKeyPressed(e -> {
                     System.out.println("Pressed");
                     pressed = true;
        });
        stage.setScene(new Scene(toTest));
        stage.show();
        stage.toFront();
    }

    @Test
    public void test_keyPressed_D() {
        clickOn(toTest);
        press(KeyCode.D);
        WaitForAsyncUtils.waitForFxEvents();
        assertTrue(pressed);
    }
}
```

Is there something that I'm missing here? In real application, when i press a key the event is catched correctly.

Comment: keys are delivered to the focusOwner only

Comment: Thank you, but how could I test it? I already simulate a click on the panel before pressing the key, shouldn't give focus to it?
And in the real application, if I press a key the event is handled, so how can i simulate this in testfx?

Comment: I want to add that if the Pane has method setOnKeyPressed it means that it can manage pressing of keys, and infact in the real application It works. The problem is just in TestFx or there is something wrong in my setup. Could you show me a way to test it?

Answer (score 2):

I figured out how to test it, it's needed to explicit request focus for the Pane.
Simply adding this line `toTest.requestFocus();`.

This test pass:

```
public class MainPanelTest extends ApplicationTest {

    Pane toTest;
    boolean pressed = false;

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) {
        toTest= new VBox(new Canvas(800,800));
        toTest.setOnKeyPressed(e -> {
                     System.out.println("Pressed");
                     pressed = true;
        });
        stage.setScene(new Scene(toTest));
        stage.show();
        toTest.requestFocus();
    }

    @Test
    public void test_keyPressed_D() {        
        press(KeyCode.D);
        WaitForAsyncUtils.waitForFxEvents();
        assertTrue(pressed);
    }
}
```